# 302 redirect to signup with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: redirect, nginx, proxy

I have a working multisite install configured in Apache. The server is a Debian GNU/Linux 8 amd64 and Wordpress is version 4.6.1. Apache is version 2.4.23 as available in the Debian repos. It's a live site and with Apache only everything is ok. I'm trying to configure it so that it works with NGINX as reverse proxy in front of Apache (NGINX version 1.10.1 as available in Debian repos).

When only Apache is running, it listens to the public IP address. When I try to enable NGINX, Apache listens to 127.0.0.1 and NGINX listens to the public IP address. I've replaced the real domain name with example.com, and the real IP address with 1.2.3.4 for this question.

Here is the Apache virtualhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
    ServerName example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/web1/example.com

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/web1/example.com
    <Directory /var/www/web1/example.com>
        Require all granted
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-ssl.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-ssl.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

    <IfModule pagespeed_module>
       ModPagespeedDisallow "*/wp-admin/*"
    </IfModule>

 </VirtualHost>
```

Here is the NGINX configuration:

```
proxy_cache_path /srv/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=nginxcache:100m inactive=2880m use_temp_path=off;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

server {
    listen          1.2.3.4:443 ssl http2;
    ssl         on;
    server_name     example.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    keepalive_timeout    60;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;

    location / {
        proxy_cache nginxcache;
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

        proxy_pass  https://127.0.0.1;
        proxy_cache_use_stale updating error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_cache_lock on;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_hide_header       Upgrade;
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1 https://example.com;
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant part of wp-config.php

```
<?php
/** Enable W3 Total Cache */
define('WP_CACHE', true); // Added by W3 Total Cache

if ( (!empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])) ||
     (!empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) ) { 

// http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-behind-reverse-proxy-1
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];

define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

// http://wordpress.org/support/topic/compatibility-with-wordpress-behind-a-reverse-proxy
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
/* [ ... usual WP config omitted ] */
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' ); 

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

And finally the .htaccess file (I know, this one is quite a mess, but please keep in mind that without NGINX it works):

```
###### BEGIN WP_OPTIMIZE_BY_XTRAFFIC_CONFIGS_WP-OPTIMIZE-BY-XTRAFFIC ######
Options -Indexes
###### END WP_OPTIMIZE_BY_XTRAFFIC_CONFIGS_WP-OPTIMIZE-BY-XTRAFFIC ######
### BEGIN WPOPTIMIZEBYXTRAFFIC ###
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
ModPagespeed on
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml  application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"

ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"

ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 3600 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 3600 seconds"

ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 15552000 seconds"

ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 15552000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 15552000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 15552000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 15552000 seconds"
ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 15552000 seconds"
ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 15552000 seconds"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 15552000 seconds"
ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 15552000 seconds"

ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 15552000 seconds"

ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 15552000 seconds"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 15552000 seconds"
ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 15552000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 15552000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 15552000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 15552000 seconds"

ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 15552000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 15552000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 15552000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 15552000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 15552000 seconds"

ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 15552000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/octet-stream "access plus 15552000 seconds"
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=15552000"
        Header set Pragma "public"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=15552000"
        Header set Pragma "public"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=15552000"
        Header set Pragma "public"
    </filesMatch>

    Header set X-Powered-By "WP Optimize By xTraffic/4.1.11"
    Header set Server "WP Optimize By xTraffic/4.1.11"
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*(wp-includes|wp-content|wp-admin|\.php).*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(2.0\ MMP|240x320|400X240|AvantGo|BlackBerry|Blazer|Cellphone|Danger|DoCoMo|Elaine/3.0|EudoraWeb|Googlebot-Mobile|hiptop|IEMobile|KYOCERA/WX310K|LG/U990|MIDP-2.|MMEF20|MOT-V|NetFront|Newt|Nintendo\ Wii|Nitro|Nokia|Opera\ Mini|Palm|PlayStation\ Portable|portalmmm|Proxinet|ProxiNet|SHARP-TQ-GX10|SHG-i900|Small|SonyEricsson|Symbian\ OS|SymbianOS|TS21i-10|UP.Browser|UP.Link|webOS|Windows\ CE|WinWAP|YahooSeeker/M1A1-R2D2|iPhone|iPod|Android|BlackBerry9530|LG-TU915\ Obigo|LGE\ VX|webOS|Nokia5800).* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_user_agent} !^(w3c\ |w3c-|acs-|alav|alca|amoi|audi|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-|dang|doco|eric|hipt|htc_|inno|ipaq|ipod|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-|lg/u|maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|palm|pana|pant|phil|play|port|prox|qwap|sage|sams|sany|sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo|teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|wap-|wapa|wapi|wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda\ |xda-).* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ ce|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/wp-optimize-by-xtraffic-optimize-cache/data/%{SERVER_NAME}/https/pc/$1/data/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/wp-optimize-by-xtraffic-optimize-cache/data/%{SERVER_NAME}/https/pc/$1/data/index.html" [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*(wp-includes|wp-content|wp-admin|\.php).*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(2.0\ MMP|240x320|400X240|AvantGo|BlackBerry|Blazer|Cellphone|Danger|DoCoMo|Elaine/3.0|EudoraWeb|Googlebot-Mobile|hiptop|IEMobile|KYOCERA/WX310K|LG/U990|MIDP-2.|MMEF20|MOT-V|NetFront|Newt|Nintendo\ Wii|Nitro|Nokia|Opera\ Mini|Palm|PlayStation\ Portable|portalmmm|Proxinet|ProxiNet|SHARP-TQ-GX10|SHG-i900|Small|SonyEricsson|Symbian\ OS|SymbianOS|TS21i-10|UP.Browser|UP.Link|webOS|Windows\ CE|WinWAP|YahooSeeker/M1A1-R2D2|iPhone|iPod|Android|BlackBerry9530|LG-TU915\ Obigo|LGE\ VX|webOS|Nokia5800).* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_user_agent} !^(w3c\ |w3c-|acs-|alav|alca|amoi|audi|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-|dang|doco|eric|hipt|htc_|inno|ipaq|ipod|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-|lg/u|maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|palm|pana|pant|phil|play|port|prox|qwap|sage|sams|sany|sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo|teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|wap-|wapa|wapi|wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda\ |xda-).* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ ce|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/wp-optimize-by-xtraffic-optimize-cache/data/%{SERVER_NAME}/http/pc/$1/data/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/wp-optimize-by-xtraffic-optimize-cache/data/%{SERVER_NAME}/http/pc/$1/data/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>
### END WPOPTIMIZEBYXTRAFFIC ###
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # mod_headers, y u no match by Content-Type?!
    <FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|svgz|ico|webp)$">
      SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</IfModule>
## BEGIN Enable GZIP Compression ##
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</IfModule>
## END Enable GZIP Compression ##


## BEGIN Vary: Accept-Encoding Header ##
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
## END Vary: Accept-Encoding Header ##


## BEGIN Expires Caching (Leverage Browser Caching) ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 2 week"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 week"
</IfModule>
## END Expires Caching (Leverage Browser Caching) ##
```

---

**The problem is that when I have the above configurations in place, the result, client-side, is a 302 redirection loop to the WordPress signup page.**

```
$ curl -I 'https://example.com'
HTTP/2 302 
server: nginx/1.10.1
date: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 06:08:50 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 0
location: https://example.com/wp-signup.php?new=
x-proxy-cache: MISS

$ curl -I 'https://example.com/wp-signup.php?new='
HTTP/2 302 
server: nginx/1.10.1
date: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 06:08:57 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 0
location: https://example.com/wp-signup.php?new=
x-proxy-cache: MISS
```

I don't know what I should try. I understand it's WP redirecting, because  the new URL can only be generated by some wp code, but I fail to imagine why it is happening. What am I missing?

Comment: you mean, that if anyone access` example.com` (or any other url), it is redirected to `wp-signup.php`?

Comment: @TazoTodua worse, anyone accessing `example.com/`, or *any other url* under the configured domain, gets a redirection loop to `example.com/wp-signup.php`, because `example.com/wp-signup.php` is included in the *any other url* set.

Comment: try to comment(remove) some parts from nginx and then visit website. If not helps, then redo that change, and then remove another part in nginx, and so on... until you will find which line may cause that.